# Magento Adding a new Language?

Tags: magento-1.9, store-view, localisation

I've looked at several pages regarding adding another language support to the Magento cart, however, there seems to be something missing.

[The usual is to download translation through the admin interface....](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/) Then Create a Store View and set the Locale to the desired language.  This doesn't appear to work as I have tried adding Russian language support only to find that the switch causes the site to come out with error and become inaccessible.

I remember about a year ago finding some mentions of the directories that needed to be created on the server in order for the language to be available.

Comment: Is the language on another domain? kind of depends on how you create the storeviews wether or not you need to make subdirs.
Did you take a look at this article and it's comments?
http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/adding-a-new-language-in-magento/

Comment: It's kind of irrelevant for the question.  And yes I looked at the link and that is the one I was referring to.

Comment: what is the error that you see? Do you use mod_rewrite? Do you use "add store code to url"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What I usually do to add russian language:

1. Add store view and assign russian locale to it like it is done in your link
2. Download russian translation by us (ET) from [this topic](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/767/P435/#t405914) (Niro comment) and install it manually

That's it!

I know that there are some cases similar to yours and usually it means that you have tried to install translation from Magento Connect. The problem is in permissions. It is much easier and safer to install it manually.

And why unofficial translation? Well, because official one is too bad.

And if this doesn't help you, it would be great to see, what your error looks like. It will be easier to find the source of the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Some locale packages seem to be packed wrong. After installing instead of expanding into their locale folders such as ru_RU, they are expanded in locale, which obviously is wrong.
I have met few of those. Creating corresponding locale folder and moving the files in it usually solves the problem. Don't forget to flush cache after that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add another language, you can download it from the [website](http://www.magentocommerce.com/translations) and copy it to `app/locale/{language_code}`. For example for czech language you have `/app/locale/cs_CZ/*.csv`.

Magento has three types of translation that are loaded in this order:

1. `app/locale/{language_code}`
2. `app/design/{area}/{theme_package}/{theme}/locale/translate.csv`
3. online translate in db